# How to convert request parameter to EnumType using Enum field in Play Framework

Tags: java, enums, playframework

I am new to Play framework and I am not able to convert the POST request body parameter to Enum type using Enum field Value.
I have Enum Fruits defined as:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum Fruits {
APPLE("apple"),
BANANA("banana"),
KIWI("kiwi"),
DRAGON_FRUIT("dragonFruit");

private final String fruitName;

private static final Map<String, Fruits> fruitsByFruitName; 

static {
fruitsByFruitName = new HashMap<>(); 
fruitsByFruitName.put("apple", APPLE);
fruitsByFruitName.put("banana", BANANA);
fruitsByFruitName.put("kiwi", KIWI);
fruitsByFruitName.put("dragonFruit", DRAGON_FRUIT);
}

public static Fruits fromFruitName(String fruitName) throws InvalidEnumException {
     if(fruitsByFruitName.contains(fruitName)) return fruitsByFruitName.get(fruitName);
     else throw new InvalidEnumException("message");
} 

}
```

I have my model class as:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyReqBody {
private Fruit favFruit;
}
```

My request body consists of json Body as:

```json
{
"favFruit": "banana"
}
```

I am trying to Bind the parameters using:

```java
Form<MyReqBody> request = Form.form(MyReqBody.class);
request = request.bindFromRequest();
```

I am not able to populate `favFruit` field of `MyReqBody` after biding, it is null. I can bind it successfully if I send "BANANA" in the request body instead of "banana", i.e. the exact enum name.
How can I tell the play framework to use compare request body data with the enum field `fruitName` instead of Enum name or How I can tell play to use `fromFruitName` while biding `Fruits` enums type?

Comment: You havent shown us your POST request code, but it sounds like a simple issue of case differences, this can be solved by using something like `String.toLowerCase()` a basic example might be `if(firstString.toLowerCase().contains(otherString.toLowerCase())){...}`

Comment: Hi, No no. It's not about case differences, my bad I took such examples. I have updated the question, look at DRAGON_FRUIT. The question is not about how to map `fruitName` to `FRUIT` but about how to tell the Play framework to use my custom converter during binding, for example even if I go with your suggestion of `String.toLowerCase` where should I put this snippet? How to tell Play to use `fromFruitName` for binding request param to enum?

Answer (score 0):

try it with the `String#toUpperCase()` method

```
if(fruitsByFruitName.contains(fruitName.toUpperCase())) {
    return fruitsByFruitName.get(fruitName.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: Hi, No no. It's not about case differences, my bad I took such examples. I have updated the question, look at DRAGON_FRUIT. The question is not about how to map `fruitName` to `FRUIT` but about how to tell the Play framework to use my custom converter during binding, for example even if I go with your suggestion of `String.toLowerCase` where should I put this snippet? How to tell Play to use `fromFruitName` for binding request param to enum?

Comment: Already tried to implement your own Binder by extending eg `PathBindable`?

Comment: No, I am not aware of it. I am new to Play. Can you please share any such references or examples? Also, this variable that I want to bind is inside json POST body not a Path Variable. Is there any different thing to extend for it?